# I need help for face inserting

Tags: faces

I need help . when I try to insert a square face, the top and bottom side do not move like the ones on the side. what settings should i make? https://imgur.com/bDReEOk?fbclid=IwAR2ogdJfE6yuatLIS9O9xMC4CSHvTl5evV_2bsV0ZcOD7VQOtwoGW7-zlS4

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: Probably the object has a non-uninform scale. Apply the scale in Object Mode with Ctrl+A, then try again.

Comment: Thank you .It works